# Compare strings with numeric values

Tags: objective-c

I have searched many hours how to compare this two strings ( and have str1 equal str2 == YES):

This string is given by a user input in my interface (search bar)

```
NSString *str1 = @"11,2";
```

This string is a property of my model object

```
NSString *str2 = @"11.2";
```

i have tested this but it's not working

```
if ([str1 rangeOfString:str2 options:options range:NSMakeRange(0, [str1 length]) locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]].location == NSNotFound
```

Witch is the best solution to compare the two NSStrings and have `str1` equal `str2`  that returns YES ?

Edit :

I know that i can do it simply by replacing the "," by "." and the do the comparaison, but i am searching an elegant solution that take the fact that 11.2 and 11,2 are the same in different locales ( using `NSDecimalNumber` for example).

Comment: why not replace the , to . and then compare?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but i don't like this solution. The problem is that the value in my model object can equal to : 11,2 and the input can be 11.2

Comment: Can you clarify, are two strings "equal" if they differ only by one having a `,` where the other has a `.` or vice-versa (and any number of `'`'s or `.`'s may occur?

Comment: sorry i don't understand your comment. (1.2 is equal wit 1,2), ( 2.1 is not equal wit 1.2)(2.1 is not equal to 1,2)....simply number comparaison with "." == ","

Comment: If the values are actually numbers, use NSNumber to store or work with them... or build a solution around a NSNumberFormatter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've just essentially answered your own question - use `NSDecimalNumber` to parse the user's input according to the current locale. Parse your string using your locale (or better yet keep it as a floating point value. That should solve your problem apart from the standard issue that comparing floating point values for exact equality is not advised, though `NSDecimalNumber` may help you address that. HTH

Comment: The problem with this solution is if the user is in french locale and he search with "." the NSDecimalNumber will be null, and if the user is in "US" local and he search with "," the NSDecimalNumber will we null.

Comment: @samir - you can't be clairvoyant. Try the user's locale (the machines current locale), if that fails to parse try generic (English) locale. If the user's locale is X but they choose to provide input in the format of locale Y then you are stuck, not being clairvoyant, and you will either have to reject the input or include a menu in the UI for the user to indicate the locale they will follow. However this is not standard OS X, which is just to accept input in the current locale. hTH

Answer (score 0):

If you can trust user's locale settings on the machine you could use a `NSScanner` instance to scan the number string and use a float or double as your model so that you can perform proper searching.

Comment: i can't trust the user 's locale. it depends in the user's input

Comment: Then you could catch for either "," or "." while user inputs the value and save that as the value for `NSLocaleDecimalSeparator` to pass in the dictionary required by `-[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:locale]`.
This is a little hackish at the view level but let's you be more elegant at the logic level.

Comment: You are welcome. Let me know if it suits so that I can update my answer.